# Any reason not to check "Optional Features" when creating custom objects?

Tags: reporting, custom-object, chatter, activities, history-tracking

When creating custom objects, in the "Optional Features" section I can optionally check boxes for:

- Allow Reports
- Allow Activities
- Track Field History
- Allow in Chatter Groups

All these boxes seem like they add features the object otherwise wouldn't have.

It seems like checking them to get these extra features is a good idea.

But they are not checked by default so I'm wondering if there is any downside to checking them... is there good reason not to check these boxes?

Comment: It doesn't look like a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you would de-select them is to make your custom object a **`Light Application Object`**, which could then allow you to use the `Force.com App Subscription` [license type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=0).

> [Store Information That’s Unique to Your Organization](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_object_def.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0)
>
> Every custom object is classified as either an *Enterprise Application object* or a *Light Application object*. The difference between these two categories is that Light Application objects don’t support sharing, access to the Bulk API, or access to the Streaming API.
>
> If you need to track your organization’s usage of each category, create a custom report type with a primary object of User Licenses and a child object of Custom Object Usage by User License Metrics.
>
> By default, all custom objects are Enterprise Application objects. To make your custom object a Light Application object, disable `Allow Sharing`, `Allow Bulk API Access`, and `Allow Streaming API Access` on the object’s detail page.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the quick and helpful explanation.  

It sounds like the only benefit of "Light Application" objects is that you can use a cheaper Force.com license type.

I'm on an Enterprise license.  So, if I understand correctly, there is no benefit to me of designing Light Application Objects and I'll check the "optional features" boxes because I've not nothing to lose by doing so.

Comment: @TomC4 Pretty much.